# How can I know for sure when an app is terminated by the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm developing an app that relies on sessions and works based on the session *lifecycle*:

- A session **begins** when the user **launches** the app.
- A session **ends** when the user **terminates** the app.

It's a very simple and basic concept but I'm having trouble implementing it.

The problem is that this method is not reliable, it might not get called:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

There rest of **AppDelegate** methods are called during multitasking, they are of no use since they have nothing to do with the **beginning** or the **end** of a session. (even though that's what I'm using right now)

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.

    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.

    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Here's what I 've tried:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    static BOOL firstTime = YES;

    if (firstTime) {

        NSLog(@"First time!");

        firstTime = NO;
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Not first time...");
    }
}
```

And here's two examples this will not work:

1. Let's say that the battery runs out and the device shuts down. Next time you launch the app it will be considered as a first time launch even though it is not. It is considered a first time launch only after the user terminates it.
2. The app crashes, next time it launches it is considered a first time launch but the session hasn't ended. A crash is not a termination by the user.

I don't know if I have reached a dead-end yet that's why I'm asking for your help.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a way to always know when the **user** deletes the app from multitasking. If the app crashes, or phone battery dies or it gets terminated for any other reason except for the user having swiped up in multitasking thats fine with me...

Comment: You should really assume that that method will never be called and look at a different trigger for session end

Comment: The app doesn't need to run in the background. I'm just looking for a way to know when the user swipes the app upwards to delete from multitasking. That's all! And even for that there's no reliable answer... why is the appWillTerminate there anyway?

Comment: You can't know. There is no difference between the user killing the app or the OS killing the app.

Comment: You need to push back on that definition of session.

Comment: It's there for historical reasons, it was called in very early versions of iOS...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution and I'm reasonable sure there isn't one. To my knowledge there is no way to do this because the OS simply might choose to stop your app cold. Not giving it any chance to execute any code. For example a unix kill command will do this. You can register signal handlers but depending on what the kill is, they still may not get run. And Apple may not accept your app.

I presume from you explanation that you are trying to maintain some sort of session on a server. If this is the case then I think you need switch from trying to manage it on the device to managing it on the server. probably with some sort of inactivity timeout.

However what I would really consider doing is switching your session management into the Active boundaries. It will mean there is only a session when you app is active which will be more reliable.

Ultimately though, stateless is the way to go. Avoiding sessions wherever possible will create a much more reliable and simpler app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to maintain sessions like this is to use `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to end the previous session and start the new session.

This does mean that a "session" may last a really long time, but that's the fault of choosing a definition for *session* that doesn't match with what the OS allows.